Problem with selector in CMD, closes after user type the entry
I am developing a script in which I need the user to select from a list that provides them with the tool they want to use and that depending on this input takes them to the other part of the code. However, since I don't know much about batch language, I asked ChatGPT and with similar projects that I saw on this site, I tried to do it. The problem in general is when the user types the number and presses enter, the program closes immediately. This is my code:
echo 1. Temporary Cleaning.
echo 2. Installation of Applications.
echo 3. Application Update.
echo 4. Exit
echo.
echo.

:digitnumber
set /p ntool= Enter the number of the tool you need:
set "vnumber=false"
set "nvalid= 1 2 3 4 "
for %%A in (%invalid%) do ( if "%ntool%"=="%%A" (
            set "vnumber=true"
            goto validnumber
        )
)

:validnumber
if "%vnumber%"=="true" (
   
    if "%ntool%"=="1" (
        echo You have selected option 1.

    ) else if "%ntool%"=="2" (
        echo You have selected option 2.
        
    ) else if "%ntool%"=="3" (
        echo You have selected option 3.
        
    ) else if "%ntool%"=="4" (
        echo You have selected option 4.
        
    )
) else (
    echo Invalid selection. Please select a valid option (1-4).
    goto enter number
)

pause

`
If you can help me I would really appreciate it.
I ran the code part by part and apparently the problem lies after checking whether the variable is a valid number or not. But I do not know what to do

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Please consider choice which is designed for the option-choice task. Use the search facility for [batch-file] choice eg. Gerhard's example or see the documentation - choice /? from the prompt.

Please read: How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input? The example for fail-safe, secure and very efficient usage of command CHOICE in the referenced answer would make your code shorter, fail-safe, secure, efficient and working too.

See also: DosTips forum topic: ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/ The command line echo. results always in accessing the file system for searching for an entry (file name, directory name, link) with name echo in the current working directory. The usage of echo/ or echo( avoids that file system access and just outputs the empty line.

There are few issues with your code
I. You are setting variable nvalid but in the for loop you are using  invalid
II. Batch script does not support else-if constructions so you need additional goto
III. Echoing string within else with brackets will take the closing bracket as the end of the else statement so you need to escape them or other type of brackets (in this case I've fixed with rectangular ones)
echo 1. Temporary Cleaning.
echo 2. Installation of Applications.
echo 3. Application Update.
echo 4. Exit
echo.
echo.

:digitnumber
set /p ntool= Enter the number of the tool you need:
set "vnumber=false"
set "nvalid= 1 2 3 4 "
for %%A in (%nvalid%) do ( if "%ntool%"=="%%A" (
            set "vnumber=true"
            goto validnumber
        )
)

:validnumber
if "%vnumber%"=="true" (
   
    if "%ntool%"=="1" (
        echo You have selected option 1.
        goto :endif
    )
    if "%ntool%"=="2" (
        echo You have selected option 2.
        goto :endif
    ) 
    
    if "%ntool%"=="3" (
        echo You have selected option 3.
        goto :endif
    ) 
    if "%ntool%"=="4" (
        echo You have selected option 4.        
        goto :endif
    )
) else (
    echo Invalid selection. Please select a valid option [1-4].
    goto :digitnumber
)

:endif
echo --END--

pause


Omg thanks, it works perfectly. Now I understand what was wrong. <3
